# Facebook messenger bot Persistent Menu button

Tags: facebook

I need to have a Facebook Messenger Bot persistent menu item "Send Message" which should not trigger a postback. Instead place the cursor on the messenger textbox. Is there a way to create the menu item without having the menu item type as "postback" or "web_url"

Answer (score 0):

"Send a Message" menu item appears automatically on mobile device when a persistent menu is created. Its not needed on web.

Comment: in my case, it didnt appear automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Check the code from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/messenger-profile/persistent-menu

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "persistent_menu":[
    {
      "locale":"default",
      "composer_input_disabled":true,
      "call_to_actions":[
        {...
```

Change composer_input_disabled to false.